# To prove that if $G$ is not bipartite, then $f(v) \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ for all $v \in V(G)$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected graph and suppose that $f : V(G) \to \Bbb{Z}$ is a function with the property that $$f(u) + f(v) \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$ for every edge $uv$. To prove that if $G$ is not bipartite, then $f(v) \equiv 0 \mod 3$ for all $v \in V(G)$.

---

I started with the assumption that $G$ is a connected bipartite graph. Then concluded that the vertex set can be partitioned as vertices such that $f(v) \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $f(v) \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. So there can't be any vertex with $f(v) \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ .

I am not feeling convinced with my own argument.

Comment: You’ve proven if $G$ is bipartite, then there is a non-zero (modulo $3$) $f.$ That is very different than proving if there is an $f$ which is somewhere nonzero mod $3,$ then the graph is bipartite.

Comment: Hint for a direct proof, not using contradiction: if $G$ is not bipartite, then we can find an odd cycle. First proof on the odd cycle $f$ is zero. Then proof that all $f$ are zero by connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly one of the following two cases can occur. In the first case the graph can be arbitrary and $f$ is constant $0 \pmod3$. In the second case the graph is bipartite.

Case 1) $f(v)\equiv 0\pmod 3$ for some vertex $v$,

Case 2) $f(v)\not\equiv 0\pmod 3$ for all vertices $v$.

In case 1, all vertices $u$ adjacent to $v$ have $f(u)\equiv 0\pmod 3$. Since the graph is connected, every vertex $w$ is connected to some vertex $w_1$ which is connected to ... which is connected to $v$ we deduce that $f(w)\equiv 0\pmod 3$ for all vertices $w$ of the graph, and there are no restrictions on the graph.

In case 2, let $A$ be the set of vertices $w$ with $f(w)\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $B$ be the set of vertices $w$ with $f(w)\equiv 2\pmod 3$. Your condition implies that vertices from $A$ (from $B$) are adjacent to only vertices from $B$ (from $A$), so the graph is bipartite.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is incorrect. Indeed, any connected bipartite graph with $f(v) = 0$ for any vertex $v$ satisfies the property.

If you want to prove by contradiction, you should start with assuming that $f(v) \not \equiv 0 \mod 3$ for *some* vertex $v$, and then prove that the connected graph is bipartite.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I was incorrect.